# Class inheritance with Hibernate and hbm2java

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm2java

I am generating my domain objects from my hbm files with hbm2java and now I want them to all inherit a base class. This class will have some utility methods for dealing with listeners. It does not really need to be persisted and I am hoping that I would not have to do a hbm file for it since it will be abstract and only have methods. Is there a meta tag or something to have all generated class extend another class?

Or is this such a lame design that it simply cannot be done with hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember doing this way back. See this: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html_single/#d0e4159

Basically you want to use a meta tag here with attribute *extends* for a common base class or *implements* for a common base interface.